# jQuery: Drag & Drop Image Into a textarea to place <img> tag into text

Tags: jquery, forms, drag-and-drop, textarea, thumbnails

Looking to use jQuery to allow the user to drag an image thumbnail from a column of images into a form textarea. When the user drags the image into the text area, a full img tag is added to the textarea, as the form supports HTML insertion (is part of a CMS)

Ideally the text added would look like this:

```
<img src="the src attribute of the image that was dragged in" alt="the alt tag of the image that was dragged in" />
```

The image column itself would be populated by a dynamic list of images, and it would contain a simple photo upload form that would update using AJAX. So users could easily upload a photo, then drag it into their blog post / textarea field. I know how to do this part, just not the drag and drop portion!

Thanks in advance.

Scott

Comment: scott , to get a start start looking at this http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ , this will definetly give you some idea

Comment: even this jquery animate function , http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: maybe this article [Native Drag and Drop](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/ "Native Drag and Drop")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320081/jquery-drag-and-drop-images-attribute-into-textarea might help