# jquery drag and drop image's attribute into textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I've been having a problem while testing drag and drop functionality. I need images to be draggable into a textarea, and when dropped, the text would be appended by a twitter username stored inside "data-twname" custom html attribute.

Problem appears when I type text inside the textarea - any subsequent drag&drop simply does not append twitter name to the text, even though it works in start. This is the jQuery code I use:

```
$(".draggie").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 100
});
var targetName;
$(".draggie").mousedown(function(){
    targetName = $(this).attr("data-twimage");
});
$("#textCompose").droppable({
    accept: ".draggie",
    drop: function(event) {
        $("#textCompose").append(targetName);
    }
});
```

I've made a demo here, to clarify: [drop demo link](http://blazevic.com.hr/dropdemo/test.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you can't append the value in case you already inserted some text. I created an fiddle for your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QQWHg/

Replace:

```
$("#textCompose").append(targetName);
```

with:

```
$('#textCompose').val($('#textCompose').val() + targetName);
```

Comment: Thanks, what a simple solution, yet I couldn't think of it. Cheers! :)

Comment: Btw. if an answer helped you to solve your problem it would be good if you mark the answer as "answered". Else maybe people won't spend their time for helping you in the future - just as a sidenote.. Glad I could help =)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting used to the interface, so, sorry :)